# Propagate data from an action to another reducer

Tags: redux

I have a custom scrollspy. There are two components. The flat list and the nested directory. The list has a onscroll handler that dispatches action "scrolled". The reducer then returns a new state that reflects whether the directory should have position static or fixed and what the current section is. Now, I don't know how to tell the directory module that the current section has changed. Dispatching an action from the list reducer seems not recommended. I don't know how to add a listener in the directory module because I don't know how to access the store directly. I only have it in the react components through context. I am using the react redux starter kit.

Update: A sample of my source code

```
TrackList/component.js
componentDidMount() {
    let {scrolled} = this.props;
    window.onScroll = scrolled;
}

TrackList/module.js
scrolled(state, action) {
  if (conditions) {
    new_state = make_directory_static_reducer(state);
  }
  else {
    new_state = make_directory_fixed_reducer(state);
  }

  let current_section = get_current_section();
  new_state = current_section_reducer(new_state, current_section);

  return new_state;
}

TrackDir/module.js
action_handlers = {
  set_current_section() {
    // I don't know how to run this when current section is set
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method to connect your React component to a Redux store?

Comment: Sure, that's how I connect the dispatchers and state to the react component. But when I say import { connect } from 'react-redux'; export default connect(map_state_to_props, map_dispatch_to_props)(TrackList); there's still no obvious way to access the store in the module.

Comment: To update the store, you need to dispatch an action. To get the value from store, you can use the `connect()`. Generally it is not a good idea to access the store directly in components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have moved some logic to the component. Now the react component itself handles the onscroll event and based on the element offsets, fires appropriate actions. This even feels right because it greatly reduces the amount of data passed around between the module and the reducers and the logic in the component is very tightly coupled to the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it would be very helpful to see a simplified example of your code. But I think I understand what your problem is, and @ming-soon has the right idea:

So you're trying to get your FolderComponent to be aware of a state change that originates in a different component. Totally possible. Here's a quick description the data flow and how Redux makes it happen:

1. Your ListComponent detects a scroll event and dispatches a `scrolled` action.
2. Your reducers run and create a new state complete with the static/fixed flag (or however you have it in your state).
3. The new state is propagated through your app to all connected components, including your FolderComponent.
4. `mapStateToProps` for your (connected) FolderComponent get called, receives the updated state, and passes the static/fixed flag into your FolderComponent on `props`.
5. Your FolderComponent re-renders, making the appropriate css change based on the static/fixed flag in its `props`.

If that flow doesn't make sense, then go do some more reading in the [Redux Docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/) (they're really good). Especially look at the Data Flow and Usage With React sections. Good luck!